# High Sierra restored from ISO to USB drive stops at the stop sign

Tags: usb, startup, crash, kernel, bootable-disk

I've restored macOS High Sierra ISO file (downloaded from Torrent) to pendrive (16GB SanDisk's Cruzer Dial) using *Disk Utility*, however when booting from it (by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> and selecting the drive), it stops on the screen which shows the white stop sign on the gray background.

So I've booted with verbose mode enabled (by holding pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> at the start), but the messages aren't clear on what it's failing.

Few messages from scrambled screen are:

> IOUSBHostDevice::message: kUSBHostMessageRemoteWake
>   IOUSBHostDevice::forcePowerGated: kPowerStateSuspended completed with 0x00000000 after 15ms

[image: macOS bootable USB drive, fails on stop sign, scrambled screen of death]

<sup>Note: The above black screen is showing booting still in progress.</sup>

[image: macOS bootable USB drive, fails on stop sign, scrambled screen of death]

[image: macOS bootable USB drive, fails on stop sign, scrambled screen of death]

[image: macOS bootable USB drive, fails on stop sign, scrambled screen of death]

I don't know how to read these scrambled screens. I've tested on both MacBook Air and Pro and the same thing is happening. The High Sierra was booting before, but not anymore. Restoring the image couple of times (even different High Sierra images) didn't help. It tries to boots to some point, but it stops at the stop sign. The pendrive is brand new and *Disk Utility* (*First Aid*) doesn't report any issues with it.

What does the above screens means? How I should correct, proceed or debug this further?

Comment: You said, "I've restored macOS High Sierra ISO file into pen drive", well macOS does not come on an ISO file, and if you want to boot the macOS Installer from USB, then properly create a macOS USB Installer following the directions in: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

Comment: @user3439894 I've downloaded few ISO and DMG files from torrent (can't download and install from App Store, as my OS doesn't work properly), but I'll try the method described in the link, thanks.

Comment: FWIW I would never download an OS from other then the manufacture. The potential for maliciousness is to high from a pirated source! Get a friend to download the installer officially from the App Store or go to an Apple Store for help.

Comment: @user3439894 Yep, the method from the link worked. Could you post it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a **macOS USB Installer**, follow the directions in: [How to create a bootable installer for macOS](https://support.apple.com/HT201372)

The follow is paraphrased from the link above, read the actual article for specifics.

First download e.g. **macOS High Sierra.app** from the App Store and when the installer opens, quit it without continuing installation.

Then for e.g **macOS High Sierra**, in Terminal, use the following command, modifying it as necessary:

```
sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/MyVolume
```

When prompted, type your administrator password and press Return.

When prompted, type Y to confirm that you want to erase the volume, then press Return.

Quit Terminal when done.

The bootable installer is now ready to use on a compatible Mac.

Answer (score 3):

For those trying to create bootable USB from a downloaded ISO file

In my case it was an incorrect way of burning ISO file into USB pen drive/stick using Disk Utility's restore from a downloaded standalone ISO image file. The USb pen wasn't bootable until it was created from files contained inside the ISO using the above command.

STEPS:

1. Mount downloaded ISO file by double clicking on it (will mount under /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra)
2. Run a slightly modified above command and amend source and destination paths if necessary (I used DiskUtility to erase my USB with name set to Untitled and Mac OS Extended (Jurnaled) file type as it failed on APFS file type):

   ```
   $ sudo /Volumes/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra/Install\ macOS\ High\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled
   ```

More info on different releases: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201372